# How to position tabs of a ViewPager wherever I need them?

Tags: android

I have a case in my app where a ViewPager would work perfectly, except that the tabs are placed at the top of the screen. I need the tabs to be underneath the View where I have declared the ViewPager in XML. There doesn't seem to be any swipe-able alternative to ViewPager and I can't find any info about this. So how do I arrange my Layout in this order:

- ActionBar
- ImageView
- Tabs for ViewPager
- ViewPager fragments

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: A `ViewPager` does not have tabs. You are using something else for the tabs, that happens to integrate with the `ViewPager`. Look at your layout file that has the `ViewPager`, find out what you are using for tabs, and move it as desired. If you need help with this, post the layout file that has your `ViewPager` and its tabs.

Comment: Right, technically I'm using the `ActionBar` (`getActionBar()` ) associated with the current `Activity`. I wasn't aware there was any other way to create the `ViewPager's` tabs.

Comment: @NguyenDoanTung I'm looking over that library now but I'm not seeing anything that would indicate I have control over the placement of the tabs. I've only seen the tabs placed at the very top or the very bottom. Do you know if these are the only two options?

Comment: I now see there are the options of `PagerTabStrip` and `PagerTitleStrip`. I'm looking into them to see if they will work.

Comment: Ok, yes, I am going to use `PagerTabStrip`. Thank you to you both for leading me in the right direction.